# The difference between "Hunger" and "Appetite"

Tags: human-biology

When I am "hungry", I need something to eat physically. But what about "appetite"? I think it is a psychological phenomenon. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the website ["Appetite vs. hunger"](http://bodyandhealth.canada.com/channel_section_details.asp?text_id=5819&channel_id=1055&relation_id=17814), the difference is very similar to what you were saying:

> Hunger is the need to eat.

Hunger is instinctive, it is the body's way of letting you know it needs sustenance.

and

> Appetite is the desire to eat.

It is a coordination between the brain and the stomach, this is learned behaviour.

Some further information can be found in the article preview ["The Biological Nature of Appetite"](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/986759?uid=2129&uid=2&uid=70&uid=4&sid=21102587970823) (Stellar, 1992)